# Getting the editor of a RepositoryItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I think the editor for a RepositoryItem is created dynamically. Is there a way to get a reference to the editor?

Comment: From where? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Fernando you should elaborate your question a bit more. Are you assigning a specific editor with the designer? What do you want to do and why and when, in case you get a reference to it, which you cannot do using the designer?

Comment: I want to do this at runtime---get the editor of a RepositoryItem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DevEx documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1009), you must set all the properties of the repository item. Doing so will allow the parent control to dynamically create the correct 'type' of editor. Then you add it to the control's repository items collection - ex. from documentation:

```
RepositoryItemDateEdit riDateEdit = new RepositoryItemDateEdit();
// Customize the item... 
// Add the item to the control's internal repository. 
treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(riDateEdit);
// Bind the item to the control's column. 
treeList1.Columns["Start Date"].ColumnEdit = riDateEdit;
```

Once you add the repository item to the items collection, you should be able to find and reference the editor. HTH ...